# CSS :first-child inside a ruleset, without preceeding classname. Is it possible?

Tags: css

All examples I've seen are the kind of

```
.some-class:first-child {}
```

but can I do

```
.some-class {
  :first-child {
  }
}
```

My css is not working and I think it  is because of this. In Sass I would just do `&:first-child` and it would work.

Comment: No I dont think so. I have never seen this syntax in css.

Comment: not yet, in the future yes: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting/

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't format your css like that. The nested format is only a sass thing so you will need to format as `.some-class:first-child {}` like you first stated.